# SQL Server: using Case statement in Where clause creates error

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures, dynamic

I have a dynamic procedure where an input variable can either be a date with the corresponding column being formatted as datetime OR a string with the corresponding columns being formatted as nvarchar.

If the input is a date then this would look like yyyy-mm-dd .

To cover this I tried to add the following to my Where clause but this creates the below error (if I remove this line then the rest of the procedure works as intended):

```
@searchTerm nvarchar(256) = ''

-- ...

WHERE           CASE WHEN ''' + @searchCategory + ''' <> ''dateX'' THEN
                    (A.' + @searchCategory + ' LIKE ''%' + @searchTerm + '%'')
                    ELSE
                    (A.dateX = ''' + CAST(@searchTerm AS DATETIME) + ''')
                    END

-- ...
```

**Error:**

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Can someone tell me what I have to change here to make this work ?

Many thanks in advance, Mike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put a datetime value into a string.  First cast as datetime to get it into the format you want then cast to a Varchar so it can be part of your dynamic string.

```
(A.dateX = ''' + CAST(CAST(@searchTerm AS DATETIME) AS VARCHAR(20)) + ''')
```

Or if @searchTerm is already in the format you want then you don't need to cast it

```
 (A.dateX = @searchTerm)
```

Comment: Thanks. Not sure I explained this right. So my input is nvarchar and my output - in case it is a date - should be datetime.

Comment: Did you try my solution?